# UFT 12.01 - Doesn't recognize objects in .Net desktop application

Tags: wpf, hp-uft

We are working on .Net desktop Empower application, which is completely developed on .Net 4.0 version framework. We are using UFT(QTP) 12.01 as automation tool.

when I am trying  spy on any object it's treating as SwfObject instead of it's original property, I tried recording way and it doesn't recognize properly in expected way, for ex: if I spy on Menu bar with list of icons and dropdown menus, UFT recognizing everything as single SWFObject and no use. It's behaving the same way for all the objects.

Selected ADD Ins are : Web, .Net, WPF, Active X, Visual Basic

And also "Infragistics Inc." is used as CompanyName which I have come across in Properties spy window.

We are trying to contact HP support guys too.. meanwhile can somebody post the solution if you come to know, Thanks a million in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you got solution, If not please use below help,

We are using Desktop application and it developed in Adobe flex, First we got same problem what you are facing later we found soultion, May be it will help you.

Open your desktop application with UFT tool and later try spy or object repository it will recognise.

To open application using UFT we used systemutil.run "application path"

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on [sateesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4527317/sateesh)  response, the following ways:

- launch application using Systemutil

  ```
  Systemutil.Run "C:\Program\YourApplication.exe"
  ```
- some other tips: https://www.learnqtp.com/ways-to-launch-your-application.
- HP UFT menu: Run > Record and run settings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I appreciate your help, we figured out the issue. We used Keyboard strokes for the objects which do not have tag names or recognizing the objects as a single SWFObject.